# Getting error no centroid defined for empty cluster as I try to create clusters

Tags: python, numpy, nltk, cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster 2 distributions with K-Means and using cosine similarity as a metric to define similarity. I wrote the following code. But it gives an error saying:

```
        Error: no centroid defined for empty cluster.
        Try setting argument 'avoid_empty_clusters' to True
```

I could not understand the reason for this. I need to create 2 clusters.

```
    import numpy as np
    from nltk.cluster.kmeans import KMeansClusterer
    import nltk as nltk

    np.random.seed(1)

    distr_1 = np.sin(2 * np.random.randn(100) + np.random.randn())
    distr_2 = (3 * np.random.randn(100)) + np.random.randn()

    x = list(range(0,100))

    X_train = np.concatenate((distr_1, distr_2))
    X_train = X_train.reshape(200,1)

    kclusterer = KMeansClusterer(2, distance=nltk.cluster.util.cosine_distance, repeats=100)
    assigned_clusters = kclusterer.cluster(X_train.flatten(), assign_clusters=True)

    print(assigned_clusters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of bad starting conditions it can happen that a cluster becomes empty.

Your code needs to handle this exceptional case.